# keras validation_data with multiple input

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I try to use `validation_data` method, but have a problem

```
model.fit([X['macd_train'], X['rsi_train'],X['ema_train']],
           Y['train'],
           sample_weight=sample_weight,
           validation_data=([X['macd_valid'],
                             X['rsi_valid'],
                             X['ema_valid']],
                             Y['valid']),
           epochs=nb_epochs,
           batch_size=512,
           verbose=True,
           callbacks=callbacks)
```

I get an error :

```
ValueError: The model expects 3  arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (127, 100, 8)
```

My code can run properly if I use `validation_data=None`

Here is my variables information

```
X['macd_train'].shape, X['macd_valid'].shape
(507, 100, 2), (127, 100, 2)

X['rsi_train'].shape, X['rsi_valid'].shape
(507, 100, 1), (127, 100, 1)

X['ema_train'].shape, X['ema_valid'].shape
(507, 100, 6), (127, 100, 6)

Y['train'].shape, Y['valid'].shape
(507, 1), (127, 1)
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a model definition?

Answer (score 2):

`model.fit()` takes as first argument the data input and as the second one the data output. You attempt to do that by using `[X['macd_train'], X['rsi_train'], X['ema_train']]`

However, you are not concatenating your data but only increasing the dimension of your array. You should use the `numpy.concatenate()` to have control over your concatenation over the proper axis.